# Text hypenation inside array-typed environment

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, cases

I'm trying to write a `cases` or `array` environment, inside display mode, with some long line of text. The thing is I can't achieve a linebreak. I know for certain that array won't allow this. I also know that a "brute force" solution can be achieved easily. However, before forcing a linebreak where I think it would be nice, I thought about asking here, not just for aesthetics but for learning too.

Here's the code I'm using

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %Idioma
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Codificacion
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %Para que use las formas vectoriales de las fuentes
%\usepackage{lmodern}       %Cambia Computer Modern por Latin Modern
\usepackage{mathtools}      %Paquete matemático general
\usepackage{commath}        %Funcionalidad matemática adicional, como por ejemplo, derivadas
\usepackage{hyperref}       %Links dinámicos en los capítulos y demás
\hypersetup{hidelinks}      %Configura hyperref
\usepackage{siunitx}        %Notación científica y unidades
\usepackage{cancel}         %Para tachar expresiones matemáticas
\usepackage{graphicx}       %Importar imágenes

\begin{align}
 \varepsilon_{\underbrace{ijl\hdots}_{n \text{ índices}}} = 
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{si hay dos índices iguales}   \\                               
    1 & \text{si todos los índices son distintos y son una permutación par de $1,2,\hdots n$ }   \\
   -1 & \text{si todos los índices son distintos y son una permutación impar de $1,2,\hdots n$ } 
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

Here the output:

[image: output]

It's very isolated from the rest of the text so it's impossible to take a screenshot where you can see the margins, but I think the equation number will suffice.

So, the thing is, is there an array-typed environment that allows automatic hyphenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the contents `<stuff>` inside a `\parbox[t]{<len>}{<stuff>}` of fixed width `<len>` that is `[t]`op-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %Idioma
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \varepsilon_{\underbrace{ijl\hdots}_{n \text{ índices}}} = 
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{si hay dos índices iguales}   \\                               
    1 & \parbox[t]{.6\linewidth}{si todos los índices son distintos y son una permutación par de $1,2,\hdots n$ }   \\
   -1 & \parbox[t]{.6\linewidth}{si todos los índices son distintos y son una permutación impar de $1,2,\hdots n$ } 
  \end{cases}
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the kind of thing I still have to read about and learn, using boxes, minipages, etc.

Just one more question, is there a command that references to the space it still has up to the margin? I mean, some way to tell LaTeX this will have 0.6 of the width I have until the margin. With that, it would definately be the most elegant solution.